# How can i add list of sheets to Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script, which works in a tab, which is hardcoded in the line 4 (Sheet1):

```
function fillColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const values = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat([1]);

  var toCopy;
  values.forEach((el,index)=>{
    if (el != ''){
      toCopy = sh.getRange(index+2,1).getValue();
    } else {
      sh.getRange(index+2,1).setValue(toCopy)
    }
  })
}
```

What is the correct way to add a list of tabs, to make script working in tabs Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet12? I tried some notations, but they were all erroneous.

Comment: Loop over `````````````````​`````````````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You need to loop over the sheets. There are multiple ways to do that, but since you are already familiar with the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop, you can wrap your code with another `forEach` loop that iterates over the selected sheets.
- You want to iteratively get and set values in multiple sheets, then it is a good idea to [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) the changes at the end of each sheet iteration.

### Solution:

```
function fillColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet12"]. // Add sheets here
  forEach(sn=>{ 
         let sh = ss.getSheetByName(sn);
         let values = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();                                                                               
         let toCopy;
         values.forEach((el,index)=>{
         if (el != ''){
                toCopy = sh.getRange(index+2,1).getValue();
         } else {
                sh.getRange(index+2,1).setValue(toCopy)
         }
         SpreadsheetApp.flush();
         });
   });   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through `ss.getSheets` which returns an array of the sheets in the document:

```js
for (let sheet of ss.getSheets()) {
 // Do something for each sheet
}
```

If you don’t want to iterate all of them, you can have an array of the names, iterate it, and use the name to get the sheet:

```js
const sheetNames = [
 'Sheet 1',
 'Special sheet',
 'Sheet 25',
]
for (let name of sheetNames) {
 const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name)
 // Do something with sheet
}
```

### References

- [Spreadsheet getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [Spreadsheet getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))